# Route a provider's numbers to specific extensions

Tags: asterisk

We installed asterisk VOIP server in our company and published a VOIP service in a village.

We configured inbound routing based on an extension of 4 numbers (ex: 7002) and its working fine.

A Service Provider is gonna provide us with a range of phone numbers, and we want to route each of these numbers to a different extension, so that the users of our VOIP service can reach other (external) providers networks...how to do this??

This is the extensions part in the (sip.conf) file:

```
[7000]
    type=friend
    context=default
    allow=gsm
    secret=123
    host=dynamic
[7001]
    type=friend
    context=default
    allow=gsm
    secret=123
    host=dynamic
```

And this is the internal route in the (extension.conf) file:

```
exten => _XXXX,1,DIAL(SIP/${EXTEN},,L(${calltime},3000))
    exten => _XXXX,2,NOOP()
    exten => _XXXX,3,hangup()
```

Any help please??

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to route each number to a different extension or any number to a specific extension?

Comment: each number to a different extension.

Answer (score 0):

sip.conf

```
...
[trunk-from-provider]
....
context = from-provider
....
```

extensions.conf

```
[from-provider]
exten = _12345[012],1,Dial(SIP/7000,30,Tt)
exten = _12345[345],1,Dial(SIP/7001,30,Tt)
...
```

This will route incoming numbers 123450, 123451, 123452 to 7000, 123453, 123454, 123455 to 7001, etc..

Comment: ok, the integration between the Asterisk server and the service provider uses E1 Sangoma card and it was successful.

Are your steps enough to route the inbound and outbound calls?